# How to access EncodeDecodeResult from jython zap

Tags: jython, zap

Is there a way to access EncodeDecodeResult from a python script? I cannot import it. When I create an Encode/Decode script and return a simple string I get the following error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.zaproxy.addon.encoder.processors.EncodeDecodeResult (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.zaproxy.addon.encoder.processors.EncodeDecodeResult is in unnamed module of loader org.zaproxy.zap.control.AddOnClassLoader @440b6dca)
```

When I try to import the module like this

```
import org.zaproxy.addon.encoder.processors.EncodeDecodeResult
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<script>", line 483, in process
ImportError: No module named addon
```

The first error seems to hint by saying that `org.zaproxy.addon.encoder.processors.EncodeDecodeResult is in unnamed module of loader org.zaproxy.zap.control.AddOnClassLoader`, but I don't know how to use that.

An ugly hack I found is to raise an exception with the result string which will show the result on the encoder/decoder view. That would have been somewhat acceptable if it didn't disable the module after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example of a Python (Jython) script for Zap's Encode/Decode/Hash functionality. This example simply appends the string `TEST` to the end of whatever is input.

```py
from org.zaproxy.addon.encoder.processors import EncodeDecodeResult

def process(value):
    return EncodeDecodeResult(value+"TEST");
```

I'll work on getting a template added to the various scripting add-ons.

[image]

For further reference (just in case):
https://www.jython.org/jython-old-sites/archive/21/docs/usejava.html

Comment: thank you for your reply, I keep getting `ImportError: No module named addon` on the import line

Comment: Are you using zap 2.10.0 and have you checked for add-on updates lately? You are creating the script in the Encode/Decode category right, not Standalone or something else?

Comment: Also if you have a short script that's just returning a string why is it quoting line 483 as the problem?

Comment: I made a fresh installation of zap 2.10.0 two or three days ago. The script is not short, in fact its quiet long, its a protobuf parser

Comment: ok, it seems I did something wrong, I don't even know what, it works now, thank you very much